# Cannot read text when Dracula theme selected in Android Studio in Ubuntu 16.04 OS

Tags: android, android-studio

So I am using Android Studio in Ubuntu 16.04 and this is what I am looking at:- [image: Garbage Screenshot]

Any help on how to fix this, maybe some fonts are missing or something like that

Comment: which font you are using in android studio in ubuntu??

Comment: `File->Settings->Appearance and Behavior->Appearance` set theme `Intellij` Id and editor `subpixel`

Comment: I haven't changed any font it is pre-installed fonts but before installing android studio I installed Microsoft's fonts ( ttf-mscorefonts ) to Ubuntu just in case

Comment: It works fine in Intellij Theme but I want dark color theme in Android studio, even tried File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart but that too didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

goto File->Settings->IDE Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts -> Font

select diferent font preview it if it is working fine hit saveas

Comment: Thanks but the fonts provided by Dracula themes are the best.
Found the answer though Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is due to missing font "Source Code Pro" which can be installed on Ubuntu as following:-

```
mkdir /tmp/adodefont
cd /tmp/adodefont
wget https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/archive/2.010R-ro/1.030R-it.zip
unzip 1.030R-it.zip
mkdir -p ~/.fonts
cp source-code-pro-2.010R-ro-1.030R-it/OTF/*.otf ~/.fonts/
fc-cache -f -v
```

Now in Android Studio Select File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart ->  Invalidate and Restart.